# Dynamically create jQuery Tabs Markup from PHP Array

Tags: php

What I am trying to achieve is create a jQuery Tabs markup from PHP Array. Basic intention is to add tabs and content dynamically. Both existing StackExchange answers and Google Search left me empty handed here. Finding it pretty dificult with my level of PHP knowledge.

Here are one of the many code that I have tried:

My Array:

```
    $args = array();

    $args[] = array(
        'name' => 'Shortcode Name',
        'tabname' => 'Shortcode Tab Name', //Same As Tab 4
        'action' => 'shortcodeaction',
        'icon' => 'codeicon',
        'image' => 'codeimage',
    );
    $args[] = array(
        'name' => 'Shortcode2 Name',
        'tabname' => 'Shortcode2 Tab Name',
        'action' => 'shortcodeaction2',
        'icon' => 'codeicon2',
        'image' => 'codeimage2',
    );
    $args[] = array(
        'name' => 'Shortcode3 Name',
        'tabname' => 'Shortcode3 Tab Name',
        'action' => 'shortcodeaction3',
        'icon' => 'codeicon3',
        'image' => 'codeimage3',
    );
    $args[] = array(
        'name' => 'Shortcode4 Name',
        'tabname' => 'Shortcode Tab Name', //Same As Tab 1
        'action' => 'shortcodeaction4',
        'icon' => 'codeicon4',
        'image' => 'codeimage4',
    );
    $args[] = array(
        'name' => 'Shortcode5 Name',
        'tabname' => 'Shortcode5 Tab Name',
        'action' => 'shortcodeaction5',
        'icon' => 'codeicon5',
        'image' => 'codeimage5',
    );
```

The PHP Code:

```
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $args as $arg ) {
        echo '<li><a href="#' . preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/", "", $arg['tabname'] ) . '">'.$arg['tabname'].'</a></li>';
    }

    echo </ul>

    foreach ( $args as $arg ) {
        echo '<div id="' . preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/", "", $arg['tabname'] ) . '"></div>';
    }
```

The `tabname` key value for Tab 1 and Tab 4 are same, so they should go under same tab name and tab content. This is exactly where I am getting lost. I know I can do a foreach loop to create tabs, but those two are not going under same tab instead they are creating new tab with same name.

Used this to get the count for array with unique value for `tabname`:

```
$lists = wp_list_pluck( $args, 'tabname' );

$counts = count( array_unique( $lists ));

// 4
```

Now a foreach loop will create 3 tabs, but not sure how to pass the `$args` inside the loops.

I am not asking you to do this for me, but a little head start would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This is surely bad: `<div id="' . preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/", "", $arg['tabname'] ) . '"></div>` because `id` should be unique on the HTML page. So tab1 and tab4 id will be the same. First of all, fix this.

Comment: That's exact what I want to achieve. Currently they are creating two divs with with same ID, but I want them to create a single div if the value for `tabname` is same.